# how can splice item if item existing in array?

Tags: javascript

i have one line code like this

```
$scope.selectItem.push(item['id']);
```

now i want check if **item['id']** existing in $scope.selectItem splice it.

any idea Honorable

Comment: Can we see some before/after pics?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
if ($scope.selectItem.indexOf(item['id']) !== -1) // it exists
```